# How to scale color by the combination of two values in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I have a graph where I want the color of each point to be scaled by its x **AND** y values. I.e.:

- high x **AND** high y values: darker colors
- low x **OR** low y values: lighter colors

Is this possible? and if so, how?

Comment: You can just do `aes(x, y, color = x + y)`

Comment: Just to clarify the method proposed by PoGibas, is creating a new variable: `new_var = x+y`, and the colors are mapped to that.